# 0 тестов пройдено

Tags: python-3.x

```
import unittest
from number_writer import location

class NamesTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def main(self):
        full_location1 = location(city, country)
        self.assertEqual(full_location1, 'city country')

unittest.main()
```

В терминале пишет: Ran 0 tests. Я понимаю что должен быть 1 пройденный тест. ПОчему так??? Помогите

Comment: Названия тестирующих методов должны начинаться с `test_`

Comment: А можно чуть подробнее?

Comment: Тесты = методы которые что то проверяют, имя таких методов должно начинаться с `test_`.  Попробуйте добавить пустой метод с именем начинающимся на `test_` и запустите - у вас будет 1 тест